Creating Power BI Report with values pulled from SQL Server database parameterized based on user Input
There is a table which has a year worth of data in a database that needs to be pulled and turned into a power bi report. If this was a static report it wouldn't be an issue but this report takes in user input where based on a certain date range and store range certain values needs to change.
Giving a table example which has the data



date
store
Total
interval




2-3-2023
3
50
15


2-5-2023
3
70
15


2-10-2023
5
30
15


2-13-2023
5
20
15


2-18-2023
8
40
15


2-22-2023
8
80
13


2-27-2023
3
10
13



I need to calculate a certain formula which is SUM(Total) [within specific store and interval id] / COUNT(Distinct Date)
If follow this formula the total should be
(140/2) + (50/2) + (40/1) + (80/1) + (10/1) = 225

Now when this is pulled by PowerBI, it needs the date to be there for pulling because the user will filter out date and store accordingly. The problem is that based on the filter the values of the formula needs to change dynamically based on that input and my question is if there is a way to do this?
If you were to put a record by itself per date and add it together the total would be different (300)
Any ideas on how to make the value dynamic in a parameter type of basis via SQL Server, Power BI, or SSIS?
Also note: the user cannot do anything technical and access SQL Servers only front end.

Try a DAX Measure similar to the following:
MyMeasure = 
  SUMX(
    SUMMARIZE(
      'YourTable',
      [store],
      [interval],
      "SumTotal", SUM([Total]),
      "DateCount", DISTINCTCOUNT([date])
    ),
    DIVIDE( [SumTotal], [DateCount])
  )

Which gives 215 based on your table above.
(Not 225 as 50 + 70 = 120 )

So if the sample table I gave have 2 months of data. The Dax Measure gives the full amount for 2 months. However if the user only wants one month of data within those 2 months the counts and total isn't being reflected properly. It only changes if i directly interfere in the backend which the "user" doesn't have access to.
